# Google maps updating location

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using API Google maps. When I click on the button, I call the method  `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`. But this method monitors my location, and I need to take data (coordinates) only once. What should I use in this case?

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation :CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        
        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

also you can add once `bool` variable

Comment: I used this method also with another button. Is it possible to get data only this way? There is no other way for data to be recorded in one action and coordinate monitoring will immediately stop.?